# convert string to hex throws java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: kotlin

I have a color like `#FFFFFF` and i want to convert it to `0xFFFFFF`

here is my code that converts it:

```
val hexColor = "0x${picture.color.drop(1)}".toInt()
```

when I run the project I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"0xFFFFFF"
```

any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just convert `FFFFFF` to `0xFFFFFF`, then there is no need for `.toInt()` and the rest your code should work just fine.

If you want to convert the value of the color from hex to decimal, then you can use [`.toInt(16)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) function without the radix (0x) at the beginning, like this:

```
val color = picture.color.drop(1).toInt(16)
```

Or using `Integer.decode()`, like this:

```
val color = Integer.decode("0x${picture.color.drop(1)}")
```

Comment: I need hex color as integer like `0xFFFFFF`
consider I have "#FFFFFF" and I have to convert it to integer with `0x` prefix

Comment: _"I have to convert it to integer with 0x prefix"_ - that makes no sense. Integers don't have 0x prefixes. Only hexes do.

Comment: @aneroid 
so how you can call this function 
`fun getColorNameFromHex(hexColor: Int): String {
        val r = hexColor and 0xFF0000 shr 16
        val g = hexColor and 0xFF00 shr 8
        val b = hexColor and 0xFF
        return getColorNameFromRgb(r, g, b)
    }`

Comment: Note that the **type** of `hexColor` in the function definition is **`Int`**, not a String or a HexString. So just convert your #colour to an Int and pass it in to that function. Also, `0xFFFFFF` vs `"0xFFFFFF"` - first is the hex representation (base 16 literal) of an integer. The second is a string version of that; which you don't need.

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert a hexadecimal `String` to a base10-number and back, pass the base as an argument to the `toInt()`-method: Use [`toInt(16)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) for Hex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In the expression `"0x${picture.color.drop(1)}".toInt()` the `0x` is being added to the string and then being converted to an Int. `0x` has no meaning to an Int. So convert it to an Int first:

```kotlin
"0x${picture.color.drop(1).toInt()}"
// #FFFFFF --> 0x16777215 (wrong)
```

Of course, putting 0x before decimal digits changes its meaning/value. So convert just the Int number to hex:

```kotlin
"0x${picture.color.drop(1).toInt(16).toString(16)}"
// #FFFFFF --> 0xffffff  (lowercase because that's how it's represented)
```

But it's a hex string. And **what you had before was already a hex string**, with an extra `#` before it. So just **drop that and add the `0x`**:

```kotlin
"0x${picture.color.drop(1)}"
// #FFFFFF --> 0xFFFFFF
```

If you want to store the colour as int and *print* it in hex, then combine part 1 and 2:

```kotlin
val actualColourValue = picture.color.drop(1).toInt(16)
println(actualColourValue)  // 16777215
println("0x${actualColourValue.toString(16)}")  // 0xffffff
```